# Why window.innerWidth is not equal to outerWidth when there is no vertical scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I found in Microsoft Edge, even there is no vertical scroll bar, the `innerWidth` and `outerWidth` properties of `window` object are not equal.

I tried with Chrome, also not equal.

As I tested, `outerWidth` is always 16 pixels larger than `innerWidth` in Windows 10, both for Edge and Chrome, regardless there is vertical scroll bar or not.

Can somebody explain this? Because as I understand from MDN, it should be the same when there is no vertical scroll bar. At least it shouldn't be as large as 16 pixels, considering the browser window border.

[image]

Comment: try maximizing your browser

Comment: @xianshenglu Still different by 16 pixels.

Comment: This is a serious issue for me as I want to show fullscreen video at native resolution, and my video element ends up being 16px smaller

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the OS zoom level Windows does apply automatically.

I don't have a Windows to confirm this, but I could replicate the issue on Chrome for osx by changing the browser zoom level. (Firefox keeps reporting the same values though).

So you might want to disable this Windows setting in `Start > Settings > System > Display > "Change the size of text, apps, and other items"` if we trust [this message](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/vKzRh9c8sNI).

Comment: I checked this setting, and currently it's 100%.

Comment: Yeah, I checked both of them. They are all 100%.

Comment: And if you change it to something else than 100%? If you've got some *dpi* setting, try to set it at 96 instead of 125